# Browsing all drive in WPF tree view

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, directory

I am designing a folder explorer in WPF.

I am successful to browse a perticular drive [e:] using the below code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="RootFolderDataProvider">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
            <folderExplorer:FolderExplorer FullPath="e:\" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ObjectInstance>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
        DataType    = "{x:Type folderExplorer:FolderExplorer}"
        ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=SubFolders}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<TreeView Grid.Column="0"
          Name="RootTreeView"
          Background="AliceBlue"
          Foreground="Black" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,169">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Browse">
        <TreeViewItem.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource RootFolderDataProvider}">
                <Binding.Path>SubFolders</Binding.Path>
            </Binding>
        </TreeViewItem.ItemsSource>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

How can I browse all drives, that is by Mycomputer.
Let me know if any information is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Folder browser to list all system drive in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375801/folder-browser-to-list-all-system-drive-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void LoadDirectories()
{
    var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (var drive in drives)
    {
        this.treeView.Items.Add(this.GetItem(drive));
    }
```

here is the link,

[WPF treeview Directory](http://codesdirectory.blogspot.com/2013/01/c-wpf-treeview-file-explorer.html)

here is the sample to bind in XAML

[File explorer WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/390514/Playing-with-a-MVVM-Tabbed-TreeView-for-a-File-Exp)

Comment: Is not there a way to do it in XAML?

Comment: You can just binding it in XAML

Comment: Not sure on this..Can you guide me a bit more?

Comment: It's bad practice to use Items property - it breaks virtualization and contradicts to MVVM's idea.